# Was there a '\0' at the end of every script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

**I'm wondering how did you dertermine the end of a script/file?** *I'm especially interested for old Unix versions (like V6).*

**Is there a '\0' after the last written character?**

Comment: Shell scripts are text files and as such should ideally not include *any* zero bytes, although doing so will probably not impair normal use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Userland programs under even older Unixes did not see "pad" bytes at the end of a file. I know that MS-DOS or CP/M would fill disk blocks with Ctrl-Z characters, so not only did a file reading algorithm have to check for end-of-disk-blocks, it also had to check for padding bytes.

Unixes never did that sort of thing. Programs read bytes until the end-of-file condition happens, which for the `read(2)` system call means returning 0. Unfortuately a long-running system call can be interrupted, which causes `read()` to return the error code (-1), and the global symbol `errno` evaluates to EINTR, so Unixes also traditioally introduce some goofiness into reading certain devices.

There's also a file system aspect to this all: Unix filesystems would put data into disk blocks, and keep a file-size-in-bytes value in the inode. Some other OSes only kept file size in blocks.  If data was smaller than a block, the problem bubbled up into userland, with pad bytes or other nonsense.

Comment: CP/M would fill 128-byte records with Ctrl+Z, but DOS has never done so - it's always recorded the exact file length just like Unix (though many programs did accept ^Z as an end-of-file marker).

Comment: @psmears I have seen DOS files with ^Z padding bytes, way back at the dawn of time.  I think it might have been a DOS 1.x issue, or possibly only an issue with programs that were written for CP/M and then ported to DOS 1.x.  IIRC, WordStar files had ^Z padding bytes... this would have been mid-1980's.  Note that even for a while after DOS 2.0 came out and changed everything, there were still a few programs floating around that had been written for DOS 1.x and they still worked (in other words DOS 2.x was backward-compatible).

Comment: @steveha: I suspect "written for CP/M and then ported" is the explanation (as it is for a lot of ancient weird DOS stuff :) )

Comment: How were binary files (that can contain any byte sequence) handled on systems that used padding?

Comment: @orion good question - I suggest you make it a new separate one.

Comment: usually any error/interruption will cause `read()` to return 0 - so whenever that value is returned, `errno` must be consulted. See also `read(2)` man page.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. The shell interpreter reads the file with the script using some (more or less complex) syscall wrapper (e.g. `read()` of `fread()`) and that will signal the end-of-file condition when it reaches the last byte of the file (which doesn't need to be zero).